# How to display all values of cycles?

Tags: r

I need to calculate statistics for several groups, for several indications

I enter groups as:

```
group = c(1,2,3)
```

and I go through them in two cycles.
The problem is that it only outputs the result for 1 and 3. It counts first for 1 and 2, and when it counts for 1 and 3 it overwrites the result with 1 and 3.

```
for(i in groupl[-length(groupl)]){
        for(j in groupl[-1]){
            res =      group.all(//function counts for two groups
            ******
            groupl = c(i,j),
            ****
            )
```

How to display the result for all groups?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```r
groupl = c(1,2,3)
res <- list()

for(i in groupl[-length(groupl)]){
  res[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in groupl[-1]){
    res[[i]][[j]] <- c(i,j)
  }
}
res

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 1 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 2 3
```

Note that due to the loop structure you chose, some indices are missing

Comment: My vector c takes values of any length, how can you tell it to be dynamic?

Comment: We will not move, I myself have not yet understood :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to clarify your question, but to clarify the way to make it dynamic. I'm not sure I fully understand what you need by dynamic.

Comment: I insert groups (say 1 through 6) into a vector, then loops 1 through 5 and 2 through 6 I go through the groups and compare them in function groupl, 2 and write the result to a file, only the result of comparing the last groups is written to file 1 and 6, but I would like to get all values (1-2; 1-3; 1-4 ....)